# Convert Hex String to ASCII Format

Tags: ios, objective-c, ascii

I have a Hex string like "000000000100" and I am using the following logic to do ASCII conversion, the output I am receiving is only 1 byte (\x01) But I want the output in the 6 byte format as \x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00

```
-(NSString*) decode
{
   string=@"000000000100";
   NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
  int i = 0;
  while (i < [string length])
  {
     NSString * hexChar = [string substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
     int value = 0;
     sscanf([hexChar cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "%x", &value);
     [newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
     i+=2;
  }
return newString;

}
```

How to do that ?

Comment: but i want to pass a string

Comment: Here is my answer so http://stackoverflow.com/a/37702822/6124910

Answer (score 0):

Let's first directly address your bug: In your code you attempt to add the next byte to your string with:

```
[newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
```

Your problem is that `%c` produces *nothing* if the character is a null, so you are appending an empty string and as you found end up with a string with a single byte in it.

You can fix your code by testing for the null and appending a string containing a single null:

```
if (value == 0)
   [newString appendString:@"\0"]; // append a single null
else
   [newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
```

Second, is this the way to do this?

Other answers have shown you other algorithms, they might be more efficient than yours as they only convert to a C-String once rather than repeatedly extract substrings and convert each one individually.

*If and only if* performance is a real issue for you you might wish to consider such C-based solutions. You clearly know how to use `scanf`, but in such a simple case as this you might want to look at `digittoint` and do the conversion of two hex digits to an integer yourself (value of first * 16 + value of second).

Conversely if you'd like to avoid C and `scanf` look at `NSScanner` and `scanHexInt`/`scanHexLongLong` - if your strings are never longer than 16 hex digits you can convert the whole string in one go and then produce an `NSString` from the bytes of the resultant unsigned 64-bit integer.

HTH